# Asyncronously manage connected clients while continously sending data in Python

Tags: python, websocket, python-asyncio, sanic

I have a server built in Python that uses Sanic and websockets to routinely broadcast data to clients:

```
@app.websocket("/")
async def websocket(request, ws):
  app.ws_clients.add(ws)
  await ws.send(json.dumps("hello from climate server!"))

  while True:
    try:

      data = dict()
      time_of_reading = time.ctime(time.time())
      data['climateData'] = sensor.read_data()
      data['systemData'] = get_system_data()
      data['timestamp'] = time_of_reading

      await broadcast(json.dumps(data))
      time.sleep(10) # changing this to asyncio.sleep() causes the msgs to send sporatically

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
      sensor.clear()
      pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080, workers=1, debug=False)
```

and my broadcast function which attempts to send a message, or removes a client from `app.ws_clients` if there is a `ConnectionClosed` error:

```
async def broadcast(message):
  for ws in app.ws_clients:
    try:
      await ws.send(message)
      print('attempting data send') # this line runs, but the clients don't receive the messages

    except websockets.ConnectionClosed:
      clients_to_remove.add(ws)

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
      sensor.clear()
      pass

  if (len(clients_to_remove) > 0):
    await remove_dead_clients(clients_to_remove)

async def remove_dead_clients(clients_to_remove):
  for client in clients_to_remove:
    app.ws_clients.remove(client)

  clients_to_remove.clear()
```

The client is able to connect just fine, and the server prints that it is trying to broadcast, but no message is ever received by the client.

I am using this broadcast function from another server that I wrote, and it works perfectly there. The difference with that one is that it only sends data when a client requests it. I feel the issue here is that the async cannot handle both continually broadcasting and removing clients simultaneously. I tried changing `time.sleep()` to `asyncio.sleep()`, but that only succeeded in successfully sending the messages dozens at a time, and then nothing at all for awhile.

Is there a pattern I could implement that would meet my needs, where I can send messages in an endless loop and also asynchronously manage connected clients?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that happens to stumble across this in the future - I had forgotten to use the `await` keyword prior to `asyncio.sleep()`.